# Откуда берется иконка и ее адрес в шрифтах иконок

Tags: css

Откуда берётся сама иконка в IcoMoon и как самому задавать такой адрес?

```
.icon-picture-o:before {
    content: "\e606";
}
```

Comment: [псевдо элемент before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore), [css property _content_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шрифт может содержать графические иконки и наборы символов.

Код:

```
.icon-picture-o:before {
content: "\e606";
}
```

выдает иконку из шрифта, который используется.
Чтобы получить нужную иконку, Вам нужно смотреть FAQ по шрифту, который Вы используете.

[Документация по Iconmoon.](https://icomoon.io/#docs)

Пример шрифта иконок - [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.ru/)

**UPD 1**

В иконических шрифтах таблица символов состоит из векторных иконок
вместо букв. Каждый символ в шрифте имеет свой код. В content Вы
указываете код иконки и получаете символ(иконку).

[Хорошая статья по созданию собственного шрифта.](http://rafaltomal.com/how-to-create-and-use-your-own-icon-fonts/)

Comment: т.е если не получилось то возможна ошибка в пути до файлов ? но в авесоме просто font-awesome.css подключаешь и всё ну и span class="fa home" и всё а в icomoon по другому

Comment: @LenovoID смысл работы один и тот же - в font-awesome.css подключены шрифты, из которых и берутся иконки. по icomoon документация **[тут](https://icomoon.io/#docs)**.

Comment: не смысл в том какой код - а смысл в том как самому сделать такое - что бы при указании не писать как обычно informer:before{content:'':position:;background:url();и т д} а писать самому не используя те самые примеры , просто так informer:before{content:'и сюда своё значение';}  т.е создать свой такой font

Comment: @LenovoID в вопросе было указано *Откуда берётся сама иконка в IcoMoon и как самому задавать такой адрес?* Вы не спрашивали как создать такой шрифт.

Comment: @LenovoID посмотрите [урок по созданию собственно шрифта на IcoMoon](http://www.webdesignmagazine.ru/code/custom-icomoon-font-tutorial/). Уточните пожалуйста Вы это искали?

Comment: почти - но как он узнал что элемент \600 ? откуда это 600 и что такое \ ?

Comment: icomoon и awesome это примеры , мне интересно как появляется после указания в content:'\100'; какая то картинка ?

Comment: @LenovoID Вы почему то очень не любите [google](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=icon+font+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B). В иконических шрифтах таблица символов состоит из векторных иконок вместо букв. Каждый символ в шрифте имеет свой код. В `content` Вы указываете код иконки и получаете символ(иконку). [Хорошая статья по созданию собственного шрифта](http://rafaltomal.com/how-to-create-and-use-your-own-icon-fonts/).

Comment: вот теперя ясно - но в гуг я искал - но все ссылки вели на авесоме и икомон - сделайте ваш коментарий ответом -

Comment: @LenovoID рады были помочь, обновили ответ.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDKskOH5sSw  очень подробное руководство - может быть кому то пригодится